# How to update SharePoint enterprise keywords with multiple values using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that looks at a user defined variable and updates the enterprise keywords for each item in a list that matches that value.

For instance, say you have a page in SP that has the managed metadata keywords: new, fresh, clean
I want a script that asks a user what keyword they want to swap out. So a user would specify a variable as: fresh and another variable as: fresher and it would update any item with the keyword fresh to fresher.

Here's what I 've used before but doesn't work now because there are mutliple values:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue
$webURL = <MY SP URL>
$listName = <MY LIST NAME>
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$listitems = $list.items 
$session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
$termStore = $session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
$group = $termStore.Groups["Resources"]
$termset = $group.TermSets["Wiki Categories"]
$terms = $termSet.GetTerms(100)
$wiki1 = read-host "Enter the wiki category you want to update"
$wiki2 = read-host "Enter the replacement wiki category"

$term = $terms | ?{$_.name -eq $wiki2}


Foreach($item in $listitems) 
{$wiki = $item["Wiki Categories"]
    if($wiki.label -eq $term) 
    { 
        $spitem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item;
    $taxfield = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spitem.Fields["Wiki Categories"]
        $taxfield.SetFieldValue($spitem, $term)

    $spitem.Update() 
    $spitem.File.Publish("True")
    } 
}
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is with this line:

```
$term = $terms | ?{$_.name -eq $wiki2}
```

And this line:

```
$taxfield.SetFieldValue($spitem, $term)
```

Comment: there is a tool that will do this at www.qipoint.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you passing a [TermCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termcollection_members.aspx) ($term) to [SetFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee589605.aspx) where you should pass in a [TaxonomyFieldValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvaluecollection.aspx).

You can convert them like this:

```
$taxfield = $spitem.Fields["Wiki Categories"]

$tfvc = new-object -typename Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection -argumentlist $taxfield;

foreach($t in $ term)
{
   $tfv = new-object -typename Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue -argumentlist $taxfield
   $tfv.TermGuid = $t.Id
   $tfv.Label = $t.Name
   $tfvc.Add($tfv)
}
...
$taxfield.SetFieldValue($spitem, $tfvc)
```

Comment: Does this happen in its own foreach before the $item for each or within in?

Comment: The part before '...' converts the multiple values in $term to a different collection type ($tfvc), so this can be done once for all items, before your foreach. Then replace the second parameter to `$taxfield.SetFieldValue`.